# jQuery selector editing HTML before adding to the DOM

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add some content to the DOM using a jQuery selector but I want to manipulate it before it gets added.

```
var $content = $('<h1>title</h1><h2 id="xx">remove me</h2><p>some content or other</p>');

$content.remove('#xx');

$('#output').append($content);
```

I have put this on jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/NNcG5/1/

Many thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend `$content.not('#xx').appendTo('#output');`

I also updated your JS Fiddle with the solution too, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NNcG5/1/).

Answer (score 3):

Try like this:

```
var $content = $('<div/>').html($('<h1>title</h1><h2 id="xx">remove me</h2><p>some content or other</p>'));
$content.find('#xx').remove();
$('#output').append($content);
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NNcG5/6/).

Comment: @Pointy beat you too it, but I like Martin's answer for simplicity. http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/NNcG5/7/

Comment: Yes but this answer included the correct way to remove the node :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem stems from the fact that you're creating a fragment that does not have a single top-level element. If you wrap that all in a `<div>` then it works fine.

```
var $content = $('<div><h1>title</h1><h2 id="xx">remove me</h2><p>some content or other</p></div>');
```

*edit* — oops also I changed your removal code exactly as Mr. Dimitrov did in his answer.

Comment: That doesn't necessarily work. You have to modify the `$.remove()` method, too: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/NNcG5/3/

Comment: @JaredFarrish it worked when I tried it; actually I had changed it first - I'll update the answer.